# PyQt touch certain points on pixmap

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a form with a picture on it, in this example it is a Humidity Indicator the user should be able to press the 60, 10 and 5% spot. The label should display the pressed spot.

How do I do that could somebody show me an example or is this not possible with Qt?

My code (which is pretty empty for now)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QRegExpValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp
from mysql.connector import (connection)
from datetime import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os
import sys
import DatabaseHandling

'''Convert UI file to Python'''
os.chdir("C:\\Users\Gianni Declercq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts")
os.system("pyuic5.exe M:\QtProjects\\Ui\RPI1_Third.ui -o M:\QtProjects\\RPI1_Third_ui.py")

from RPI1_Third_ui import Ui_Form3  # import after recreation of py file


class ThirdWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThirdWindow, self).__init__()

        self.dbu = DatabaseHandling.DatabaseUtility()
        self.msl = None

        # Show UI on screen + resize window
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.picInidicator.setPixmap(QPixmap("F:\QtProjects\\138691.jpg"))
        self.setFixedSize(800, 480)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = ThirdWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Example of the form

[image: Example form]

Comment: How to make a round shape button: http://www.codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/qtQPushButtonRoundShape.php#.UG3ry5jA8XF

Comment: Can I place the round button on the picture? I want to keep the picture.

Comment: Yes, you can place it.

Comment: Create a mask of the image that keeps the coloured circles and makes everything else transparent. Layer that on top of the "real" image, then use `QImage` to get the pixel colour at a given point (i.e. during a mouse-event) and test whether it's transparent.